# Finding small letter between two capital letters - MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I've got problem - I need to find every single phrase like AbC (small b, between two Capital letters).
For Example a statement:
Little John had a ProBlEm and need to know how to do tHiS.

I need to select ProBlEm and tHiS (you see, BlE and HiS, one small letter in between two capital).
How can I select this?

Comment: "Every single phrase" where? Anywhere in your database?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can use a *binary* (to ensure case sensitivity) regular expression to filter for those records that contain such a pattern:

```sql
WHERE my_column REGEXP BINARY '[[:upper:]][[:lower:]][[:upper:]]'
```

However, it is not so straightforward to extract the *substrings* which match such a pattern from within MySQL.  One *can* use a UDF, e.g. [`lib_mysqludf_preg`](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme), but it's probably a task more suited to being performed within your application layer.  In either case, regular expressions can again help to simplify this task.

Comment: Be aware of this warning from the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp): "The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte character sets."

Comment: Just a literal 'e' should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have split the String. **[Please refer this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql/)**

and then search each retrive word like

```
substring(word,2) LIKE '[A-Z]' COLLATE latin1_general_cs
```